# Depend on presence of binary in Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I want to write a package that, for simplicity reasons, requires the presence of a certain (non-Haskell) program on the system, namely PHCPack.

If it were a library, I could just add an `extra-libraries` field. How do I depend on the presence of a specific binary?

For the moment, it is enough for me if a binary with the right name is in the `PATH`.

Comment: Does your package require this binary in order to build, or merely in order to execute correctly?

Comment: It only needs it during execution.

Comment: Why fail the build artificially? You don't know how the package will be used. Maybe it will be built on one computer and used on another one. It is appropriate to warn the user if the binary is not present. The check can be done in `Setup.hs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I came up with (thanks to n.m for the suggestion). My (somewhat simplistic) Setup.hs looks like this:

```
import Distribution.Simple

import Distribution.Simple.Utils(warn)
import Distribution.Verbosity(normal)
import System.FilePath(getSearchPath,(</>))
import System.Directory(doesFileExist,getPermissions,executable)
import Control.Monad(filterM,unless)

main = do
  let hooks = simpleUserHooks {
        preConf = \args cnfFlags -> do
           info <- (preConf simpleUserHooks) args cnfFlags
           checkPHC
           return info
        }
  defaultMainWithHooks hooks

checkPHC :: IO ()
checkPHC = do
  locations <- phcLocations
  (if null locations then 
     warn normal "No PHC binary found in PATH."
   else do
     p <- mapM getPermissions locations
     unless (any executable p) $ warn normal "PHC file found, but not executable.")

phcLocations :: IO [FilePath]
phcLocations = do
  paths <- getSearchPath
  filterM doesFileExist $ map (</> "phc") paths
```

It checks for a binary called "phc" in the PATH.